# compiler error on calling boost::bind() inside boost::thread constructor

Tags: c++, boost-thread, firebreath, boost-bind, pointer-to-member

I am currently writing a firebreath C++ NPAPI plugin, and i an trying to invoke a boost::thread from inside the plugin. The platform i am building it is Ubuntu Linux 13.04. Here is the skeleton of the class declaration and relevant member function implementations:

```
class EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI : public FB::JSAPIAuto
{
public:
   EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI(const EmulatorLaunchPluginPtr& plugin, 
                          const FB::BrowserHostPtr& host):m_plugin(plugin), m_host(host)
  {
      registerMethod("launch_emulator", 
                   make_method(this, &EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI::launch_emulator));
       registerMethod("launch_emulator_thread", 
                   make_method(this, &EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI::launch_emulator_thread));
  }
    virtual ~EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI() {};
    EmulatorLaunchPluginPtr getPlugin()
    {
        EmulatorLaunchPluginPtr plugin(m_plugin.lock());
        if (!plugin) {
            throw FB::script_error("The plugin is invalid");
        }
        return plugin;
    }  

    bool launch_emulator(const std::string& ,const FB::JSObjectPtr& )
    {
         emt(boost::bind(//boost::type<void>(),
        &EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI::launch_emulator_thread,
        this,
        cmd,
                callback));
        return true;
    }
    void launch_emulator_thread(const std::string& , const FB::JSObjectPtr& )
    {
         //thread body logic here
         int result = 0;
         result = invoke_command(cmd); 
         //callback to the browser
         callback->InvokeAsync("", FB::variant_list_of(shared_from_this())(result));
    }

private:
    int invoke_command(const std::string& )
    {
        int res = system("/usr/bin/firefox"); 
        return res;
    }

    EmulatorLaunchPluginWeakPtr m_plugin;
    FB::BrowserHostPtr m_host;
    boost::thread emt;  
};

I am getting the following compile error for the code fragmented highlighted above:
```

[ 54%] Building CXX object projects/EmulatorLaunchPlugin/CMakeFiles/EmulatorLaunchPlugin.dir/EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI.cpp.o
/home/ajay/Downloads/firebreath-FireBreath-c335f5b/projects/EmulatorLaunchPlugin/EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI.cpp: In member function ‘bool EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI::launch_emulator(const string&, const JSObjectPtr&)’:
/home/ajay/Downloads/firebreath-FireBreath-c335f5b/projects/EmulatorLaunchPlugin/EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI.cpp:94:30: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::thread) (boost::_bi::bind_t&, const boost::shared_ptr&>, boost::_bi::list3, boost::_bi::value >, boost::_bi::value > > >)’
make[2]: *** [projects/EmulatorLaunchPlugin/CMakeFiles/EmulatorLaunchPlugin.dir/EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]:**  [projects/EmulatorLaunchPlugin/CMakeFiles/EmulatorLaunchPlugin.dir/all] Error 2
make: ** [all] Error 2

I am new to Boost Libraries, and i did try to understand how boost::bind works, but i could not resolve this error. Can someone please help me understand the compiler's behavior?

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: please, use C++ comments to indicate an error site, cuz '***emt(...' looks like triple dereference of `emt`. and after next `; *** return` my internal parser got ICE %)

Comment: also there is smth wrong w/ error message. it looks like partially copy-n-pasted... `call to ‘(boost::thread) (boost::_bi::bind_t&, const boost::shared_ptr&>` -- I don't see corresponding open angle bracket

Comment: @zaufi  :   Thanks for the critique...i had enclosed the compiler output in block-quotes which had caused misrepresentation of the text...please find the original error in the revised version of the post... Regards, Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line to:

```
emt = boost::thread(&EmulatorLaunchPluginAPI::launch_emulator_thread, this, cmd, callback));
```

Answer (score 0):

I still do not see the error message clearly (particularly I'm confused by `shared_ptr` w/o a template type and dangling `>` after it), but I see some errors in your code anyway:

1. `launch_emulator` uses smth that is not observable by this code. for example smth named `cmd` and `callback`. using my telepathy, I guess *missed function parameter names* (am I correct?)
2. the class contains **uninitialized** `boost::thread` instance -- you have to initialize it in ctor, because this class **do not have a copy ctor or assign operator** (for C++11 mode it have *move constructor/assign*)
3. in `launch_emulator` you call `operator()` for `boost::thread` instance. this class **do not have** such member... so I suppose your shortened error message about this fact actually...

Comment: Thanks for the comment regarding the copy-constructor...that has solved my problem!! I agree it was very basic :-)... i changed emt from being a class field to make it a local variable of launch_emulator(). The code has now compiled!